# Does the realm.io database support multi column indexes or sorted indexes?

Tags: realm

Does the realm.io database support multi column indexes or sorted indexes?

The [documentation](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/) does not mention these features, but that seems odd since Realm is billed as a replacement for core data.

Answer (score 0):

Yep!

1. Realm lets you define multiple indexed properties in a single object class by overriding the `indexedProperties` class method and returning an array of the names of the properties you wish to index. Realm mentions this in the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#indexed-properties).
2. You can sort objects by an index (Or any other property for that matter) by using the `[RLMResults sortedResultsUsingProperty:ascending:]` after querying for a group of objects. That's covered in the documentation [here](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#sorting).

Please let me know if you require any additional clarification. :)

Comment: 1) It seems that indexedProperties returns an array of columns that should be indexed, but that these are single column indexes. There does not seem to be a way to create an index that contains multiple columns.
2) sortedResultsUsingProperty seems to sort the results after querying rather than using an index that is presorted.

Comment: @JohnCashew Did you mesure the performance of using indexes in Realm compare to SQLite ? I think this is single index too