# What kind of properties should be indexed in Realm?

Tags: swift, indexing, realm

I'm using Realm now. I see on the document https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#indexed-properties , it says

> Indexing a property will greatly speed up queries where the property
>   is compared for equality (i.e. the = and IN operators), at the cost of
>   slower insertions.

So it means indexing only works when the property is being compared.
So does the indexing in Realm help to bring better performance in sorting queries, or using `BEGINSWITH` , `CONTAINS` ?

I've tested with sorting with 10k rows model but it seems indexing doesn't bring up better performance.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the docs, indexing speed up queries where the property is compared for equality. This also increases the performance of `BEGINSWITH` queries, but not `CONTAINS` unfortunately.

Comment: How's about sorting with index?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no any benefits for sorting also.

Comment: Well, i thought so too until i've read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33978682/does-the-realm-io-database-support-multi-column-indexes-or-sorted-indexes , it makes me think index can make better performance sorting queries, and index works with `ENDSWITH` too?